# What use JavaScript to develop apps for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-developer-api

I want to use JavaScript for development, like an Unity3D. But Unity3D, which is to develop games. Please, what development tools in JavaScript for Android.

Comment: can you know about phonegap?

Comment: no, I do not know about phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your talking about Mobile Hybrid Applications generally these applications are created using the java script frameworks like Angularjs React etc..

to create Hybrid Applications you can use the following famous frameworks

```
ionic http://ionicframework.com/
xamarin https://www.xamarin.com/
Phonegap http://phonegap.com/)
Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/)
```

and some more which you can google it, the above links will give you more information's about the frameworks

Answer (score 1):

you can use cordova to develop hybrid android mobile applications , this video can be helpful for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjlIECYXKlU